# Stop and Re-Start a database job with Query

Tags: sql-server, database, jobs, job-scheduling

I'm looking for a way to stop a running job after it runs for a certain period of time and then restart.

I've read up on the sp_stop_job and from what I understand, this will stop the job once the current step it is running is completed. 
I can't use that because the job usually gets stuck on a step and needs to be stopped and restarted and then it finishes fine.

I already have a job that runs and sends out an alert for jobs that have been running longer than expected, I just need a way to stop and restart a particular job that will most likely not finish the current step.

Using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Thanks
Steven

Comment: You could find the session and use the kill command on the session that the job is using and then simply re-run the job.

Comment: I found a query (added to original post) that will show me all the current running jobs that shows the Name and time it started using sysJobs and sysJobActivity but haven't been able to figure out how to match the job with the current sessions or if there was an easier way to tell which sessions are running because of a job.

Comment: I think I've found code that will do what I need it to after a little more playing around with it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @SurgeonofDeath

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.spid,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date    
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses p
ON master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(convert(varbinary(16), j.job_id)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = 
    substring(replace(program_name, 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job ', ''), 1, 34)
    WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```